# Jenkins pipeline pasing remote repository and branch

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I´m thinking to do the following but I don´t know if this will be possible.

My idea is to have a Jenkins pipeline but passing the git repository url and the branch like input parameters from other job and inside the `Jenkinsfile`, to do a checkout or something like that with the git repository url and the branch and start to compile, call the tests... etc

How do you think about that?

Thanks!

Comment: If your goal is to reuse one jenkinsfile (with parameters) on multiple projects that are similar use [jenkins pipeline shared groovy libraries plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin) instead

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'am not understanding you correctly. But any job pasing any variables should be a inside a pipline. Or do you want to combine simple jenkins jobs with the pipeline?

Comment: My idea is to have something like a launcher for each gitlab project and since here invoke the execution of a jenkins pipeline pasing like input parameters from the launcher, the git repository url and the branch

Comment: and a scm trigger won't do ?

Comment: no, in this case without scm trigger. Here the develop enviroment doesn´t exist so all the executions has to be on demand.

Comment: Maybe you can configure a start job as the first job in the pipeline which takes parameters. A "normal" jenkins Job you can trigger in many ways.